# Tests to simple Node, Express, mySQL API

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, express, unit-testing

I need to create tests for the backend of my app. The app is just a simple form creating with react-hooks-form. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    user: "root",
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    password: "password",
    database: "event_form"
});

app.post('/create', (req, res) => {
    const firstName = req.body.firstName;
    const lastName = req.body.lastName;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const date = req.body.date;

    db.query('INSERT INTO members (firstName, lastName, email, date) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
    [firstName, lastName, email, date],
    (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }else {
            res.send("Values inserted");
        };
    }
    );
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("Your server is runnih at port 3001!!!!")
})
```

How to write tests to it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a number of tools such as ***Postman***, ***ReadyAPI*** to test your web API applications. I recommend to use postman for you because it's easy to use and you can save your requests on your account.

Or, You can use CLI (Command Line Interface) tools like curl or Invoke-WebRequest.

**For Windows Powershell**

```
$myForm = @{firstname='yourfirstname';lastname='yourlastname';email='youremail';date='1999-06-13'}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:3001/create -Method POST -Body $myForm
```

**For Linux Bash**

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"firstname":"yourfirstname","lastname":"yourlastname","email":"youremail","date":"1999-06-13"}' http://localhost:3001/create
```